# Not seeing steps between factoring fractions

Tags: factoring, fractions

I'm looking to solve the limit of the following error function as s goes to 0, but I'm failing on factoring things out. My calculator (TI-89) gives me a nice form I can use, but I cannot manipulate things quite right. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong/missing?

The function starts as
$$sE(s)=\frac{s}{s^2} \left[1-\frac{K(K_1s + K_2)}{Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2}\right]$$
I multiplied so as to combine the two fractions: 
$$\frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{Ts+ KK_1 + 1 + \frac{KK_2}{s}}{Ts+ KK_1 + 1 + \frac{KK_2}{s}}$$
And I'm left with
$$\frac{Ts+ KK_1 + 1 + \frac{KK_2}{s} - KK_1s - KK_2}{Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2}$$

Unfortunately, I can't figure how to simplify out the numerator.

The calculator states the answer is $$\frac{Ts+1}{Ts^2+(K K_1 +1)s+K K_2}$$
I can deal with that, as the limit will simply be $\frac{1}{KK_2}$. But what are the steps in between? I don't know how to get rid of the $KK_x$ terms in the numerator as I need to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You made a mistake when you added the fractions. I'm not sure why you divided by $s$ everywhere. Making a common denominator gives:
$$\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{(Ts^2+(KK_1+1)s+KK_2)-(K(K_1s+K_2))}{Ts^2+(KK_1+1)s+KK_2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mistake is somewhere in how you combined the fractions initially.  Here's what the simplification should look like:
\begin{align*}
sE(s)&=\frac{s}{s^2} \left[1-\frac{K(K_1s + K_2)}{Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{s} - \frac{K(K_1s + K_2)}{s(Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2)}\\
&=\frac{Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2-K(K_1s + K_2)}{s(Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2)}\\
&=\frac{Ts^{2}+s}{s(Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2)}\\
&=\frac{Ts+1}{Ts^2 + (K K_1 +1)s + K K_2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Dang, I can't believe I missed that. I've spent over an hour reworking this thing too. Thank you... and boy do I feel stupid.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens to the best of us.